# Why I can't change an array element obtained from another class?

Tags: c#, arrays

I created a class that implements the wrapper over the array `double []` but I can not change the element of the received array. These are tests

```
public void SetCorrectly ()
public void IndexerDoesNotCopyArray ()
```

The problem sounds like this. Write the class `Indexer`, which is created as a wrapper over the array `double []`, and opens access to its subarray of some length, starting with some element. Your decision must pass the tests contained in the project. As always, you must monitor the integrity of the data in Indexer.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Incapsulation.Weights
{
    public class Indexer
    {
        double[] array;
        int start;
        int length;
        public int Length
        {
            get { return length; }
        }

        public Indexer(double[] array, int start, int length)
        {
            if (start < 0 || start >= array.Length) throw new ArgumentException();
            this.start = start;
            if (length < start || length > array.Length) throw new ArgumentException();
            this.length = length;
            this.array = array.Skip(start).Take(length).ToArray();
        }

        public double this[int index]
        {
            get { return array[index]; }
            set { array[index] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

This is tests

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Incapsulation.Weights
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Indexer_should
    {
        double[] array = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        [Test]
        public void HaveCorrectLength()
        {
            var indexer = new Indexer(array, 1, 2);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, indexer.Length);
        }

        [Test]
        public void GetCorrectly()
        {
            var indexer = new Indexer(array, 1, 2);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, indexer[0]);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, indexer[1]);
        }

        [Test]
        public void SetCorrectly()
        {
            var indexer = new Indexer(array, 1, 2);
            indexer[0] = 10;
            Assert.AreEqual(10, array[1]);
        }

        [Test]
        public void IndexerDoesNotCopyArray()
        {
            var indexer1 = new Indexer(array, 1, 2);
            var indexer2 = new Indexer(array, 0, 2);
            indexer1[0] = 100500;
            Assert.AreEqual(100500, indexer2[1]);
        }


}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what the problem or question is here. Is one of your tests not passing, and if so, which one and why?

Comment: It's look like you are reinventing [ArraySegment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing here is that the last test requires that your wrapper provides access to the *underlying* array. In other words, whatever number of Indexers are created, they **all** point to the same *underlying array*.

Your line here `this.array = array.Skip(start).Take(length).ToArray();` violates this requirement creating a new instance of `Array` class. Because of this the value changed by first indexer is not reflected in the second one - they point to different memory areas.

To fix this, instead of creating a new Array using LINQ, simply store the original array passed through constructor. Your `this[]` indexer property must take care of passed `start` and `end` adding `start` to the `index` and checking the out-of-boundaries condition manually.

Answer (score 0):

All linq extension methods create a *new enumeration*, they do not mutate or return the one the method is called on:

```
var newArray = array.Skip(...).ToArray();
ReferenceEquals(array, newArray); //returns false
```

Any change you might make in an element of `newArray` will not change anything whatsoever in `array`.

Your `SetCorrectly` test is comparing `indexer` and `array` and it will always fail. Your other test also fails because `indexer1` and `indexer2` reference two different arrays.

*However* because Linq is lazy, modifying `array` can be seen by the result of the Linq extension method depending on when you materialize the enumeration; this can happen:

```
var skippedA = array.Skip(1); //deferred execution
array[1] = //some different value...,
var newArray =skipped.ToArray(); //Skip is materialized here!
newArray[1] == array[1]; //true!
```